# Health and Medicine

Tags: game-design

I want to have a health system in my game and I was thinking that every character should have the following

- Health (HP basically) - when it reaches 0 it dies
- Wounds - physical injuries, can have multiple levels of severity (minor to lethal)
- Illness - same as wounds, but require a different type of medicine to heal
- Nutrition - they require food

The wounds will require bandages to heal and a medic to apply them. There are multiple tiers of bandages, from basic cloth bandages to sterilized bandages. Each tier of bandages are effective up to a certain severity of wounds, after the severity passed that threshold their effectiveness should decrease. The medic's skill should affect the effectiveness, "advanced" bandages should require higher skill to apply. If the medic's skill is not enough, they can still apply it, but it's effectiveness should be decreased.

The illnesses are exactly the same, but require antibiotics for treatment instead of bandages.

I want the behavior to be something in the lines of

- Low severity wounds or illnesses can heal on their own
- The severity can get worse if untreated
- The chances of recovery to be affected by the HP and the nutrition

The rest of the game is tick based, and I can update a character's state every tick.

I know "This War of Mine" has a really similar behavior, but I just can't wrap my head around on how this should be designed in a tick-based game. I came up with an idea, but it seems needlessly complicated to do.

### My Idea in a Nutshell

Represent Wound's and Illnesses' severity as a double ranging from [0.0, 1.0] where 1.0 is the worst possible illness.

The characters will also have a recovery chance, that will change every tick based on their state (severity, bandage/meds eff, HP, nutrition)

A bandage efficiency and meds efficiency will also be present on the character's state, again from [0.0, 1.0] where 0.0 means no bandage/meds and 1.0 means top tier bandage/meds applied by a skillful medic.

After a set number of ticks the recovery chance will "proc" and either completely heal the character or make the disease worse and remove any applied bandages/meds.

The problem with my approach is that I think it's way too complicated to fit into a math formula that computes the delta recovery chance.

Is there a better approach? Is my idea too complicated and I should simplify it a bit?

Comment: If you just want a sounding board for opinions on a design direction, those questions are more appropriate to ask in [chat] once you've earned the necessary 20 rep (across any sites in the StackExchange network). You're just one upvote away, if you can find a question that you can answer well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to judge how a specific mechanic is going to work in the context of a larger game. It depends on how many other mechanics you have which compete for the player's attention, how well your UI informs the player about all the information required to understand the mechanic and how many opportunities your game gives to the player to make meaningful decisions based on your mechanics.

But my gut instinct says that you are overcomplicating game mechanics just for the sake of complicating them. It is usually a better approach to design and implement a very simple solution first, do some testplaying to see how it works, and then see if adding more complexity will make the mechanics more interesting or just make your game harder to understand.

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe I just needed to hear this from someone else. The player didn't need to know about all the details going under the hood, but nevertheless it's still a complicated system. I will rethink this in order to reduce the complexity. Thank you!